# Possible to loop through thermal zones with adb commands

Tags: android, shell, adb

Is there a way to loop through all thermal_zones and get their outputs at once instead of writing `adb cat sys/class/thermal/<thermal_zone#>/temp` for each one?

```
adb cat sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
adb cat sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp
adb cat sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone2/temp
...
adb cat sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone20/temp
```

Comment: `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp`?

Comment: Thanks it worked!